# React Native make android app load in genymotion

Tags: react-native

I am trying to build an android app in react native.  I have followed the official guidelines and downloaded genymotion and created a new project in react native.  How do I open my project in genymotion?

I am getting the following error in my terminal

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

- Where:
  Build file '/Users/adamkatz/Projects/testAndroid/android/app/build.gradle' line: 69
- What went wrong:
  A problem occurred evaluating project ':app'.

  > SDK location not found. Define location with sdk.dir in the local.properties file or with an ANDROID_HOME environment variable.
- Try:
  Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.

BUILD FAILED

Total time: 6.504 secs
Could not install the app on the device, read the error above for details.
Make sure you have an Android emulator running or a device connected and have
set up your Android development environment:
https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/android-setup.html

when i added the following 
export ANDROID_HOME=/usr/local/opt/android-sdk

i get the following error message

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

- What went wrong:
  A problem occurred configuring project ':app'.

  > failed to find Build Tools revision 23.0.1
- Try:
  Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.

BUILD FAILED

Total time: 3.735 secs
Could not install the app on the device, read the error above for details.
Make sure you have an Android emulator running or a device connected and have
set up your Android development environment:
https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/android-setup.html

Comment: Can you provide more of the console output? You don't show the above error referenced in this message.

Comment: sorry i updated it correctly, it is clearly something wrong with my setup

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You must define ANDROID_HOME I copied the relevant parts from the React Native setup guide below and link below that.

On Mac, add this to your ~/.bashrc, ~/.bash_profile or whatever your shell uses:
If you installed the SDK via Homebrew, otherwise ~/Library/Android/sdk

```
export ANDROID_HOME=/usr/local/opt/android-sdk
```

On Linux, add this to your ~/.bashrc, ~/.bash_profile or whatever your shell uses:

```
export ANDROID_HOME=<path_where_you_unpacked_android_sdk>
```

On Windows, go to Control Panel -> System and Security -> System -> Change settings -> Advanced -> Environment variables -> New

https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/android-setup.html#define-the-android-home-environment-variable

Comment: okay i did as you said but now i am getting a new error, I edited the question to show

Comment: Please see the section right below the linked on on the react-native documentation. This error is because you don't have the 23.0.1 version of the build tools installed.

Comment: I have 24.4.1 installed

Comment: sorry that is the sdk tools, for build tools I have 23.0.2 so should still be good

Comment: I think my problem is setting the environment variable, what am I supposed to type in terminal to set the environment variable?

Comment: @AdamKatz no, 23.0.2 is not good. You need 23.0.1. With Android build tools you need the specific version listed. You could update android/app/build.gradle to have buildToolsVersion 23.0.2 and THEN you would be good.

Answer (score 1):

Add a properties file called `local.properties` in your android project directory (e.g. open your project named as xyz and add this file) and add:

```
sdk.dir=C\:\\Users\\jeey\\AppData\\Local\\Android\\Sdk
```

in the file and save it.

Re-run your project.

Answer (score -2):

It seems you have no build tool version 23.0.1 installed in your pc. Lunch your sdk manager and install the specified version.

For more detail.
Go through setting up React native  to use with Genny motion here 
[Android Setup - React Native](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/android-setup.html)