# react-native UI Explorer examples from GIT fails to run on Mac simulating Android with Genymotion

Tags: java, android, react-native, genymotion, building

- I was following the instructions to set up the react-native examples (UIExplorer, Movies etc.) pulled from GIT, following the instructions set up at - https://github.com/facebook/react-native
- I am attempting to set it up to preview the examples via the Genymotion Android Simulator on a Mac.
  *All previous steps regarding setup, pulling the repo, etc. are successful with no errors.
  *I then execute the following statement at the bash shell on Mac

`./gradlew :Examples:UIExplorer:android:app:installDebug`

The following error is shown while building.

> _:Examples:UIExplorer:android:app:compileDebugJavaWithJavac
>   /Users/xxx/gitRepo/react-native/Examples/UIExplorer/android/app/src/main/java/UIExplorerActivity.java:63: error: cannot find symbol
>
> ```
>   mReactInstanceManager.onPause();
>                        ^
> ```
>
> symbol:   method onPause()
>     location: variable mReactInstanceManager of type ReactInstanceManager
>   /Users/xxx/gitRepo/react-native/Examples/UIExplorer/android/app/src/main/java/UIExplorerActivity.java:72: error: cannot find symbol
>
> ```
>   mReactInstanceManager.onResume(this, this);
>                        ^
> ```
>
> symbol:   method onResume(UIExplorerActivity,UIExplorerActivity)
>     location: variable mReactInstanceManager of type ReactInstanceManager
>   2 errors
>   :Examples:UIExplorer:android:app:compileDebugJavaWithJavac FAILED
>
> FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.
>
> - What went wrong:
>     Execution failed for task ':Examples:UIExplorer:android:app:compileDebugJavaWithJavac'.
>
>   > Compilation failed; see the compiler error output for details.
> - Try:
>     Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.
>
> BUILD FAILED_

Using the --debug parameter reveals similar info

> 11:47:06.178 [INFO] [org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.compile.JdkJavaCompiler] Compiling with JDK Java compiler API.
>
> 11:47:06.434 [ERROR] [system.err] /Users/xxx/gitRepo/react-native/Examples/UIExplorer/android/app/src/main/java/UIExplorerActivity.java:63: error: cannot find symbol
>
> 11:47:06.434 [ERROR] [system.err]       mReactInstanceManager.onPause();
>
> 11:47:06.434 [ERROR] [system.err]
>                          ^
>   11:47:06.435 [ERROR] [system.err]   symbol:   method onPause()
>
> 11:47:06.435 [ERROR] [system.err]   location: variable mReactInstanceManager of type ReactInstanceManager
>
> 11:47:06.440 [ERROR] [system.err] /Users/xxx/gitRepo/react-native/Examples/UIExplorer/android/app/src/main/java/UIExplorerActivity.java:72: error: cannot find symbol
>
> 11:47:06.441 [ERROR] [system.err]       mReactInstanceManager.onResume(this, this);
>
> 11:47:06.441 [ERROR] [system.err]
>                               ^
>   11:47:06.441 [ERROR] [system.err]   symbol:   method onResume(UIExplorerActivity,UIExplorerActivity)
>
> 11:47:06.441 [ERROR] [system.err]   location: variable mReactInstanceManager of type ReactInstanceManager
>
> 11:47:06.464 [ERROR] [system.err] 2 errors
>
> 11:47:06.465 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteAtMostOnceTaskExecuter] Finished executing task ':Examples:UIExplorer:android:app:compileDebugJavaWithJavac'
>
> 11:47:06.465 [LIFECYCLE] [class org.gradle.TaskExecutionLogger] :Examples:UIExplorer:android:app:compileDebugJavaWithJavac FAILED
>
> 11:47:06.466 [INFO] [org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.AbstractTaskPlanExecutor] :Examples:UIExplorer:android:app:compileDebugJavaWithJavac (Thread[Daemon worker Thread 4,5,main]) completed. Took 0.319 secs.
>
> 11:47:06.466 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.AbstractTaskPlanExecutor] Task worker [Thread[Daemon worker Thread 4,5,main]] finished, busy: 5.546 secs, idle: 0.049 secs
>
> 11:47:06.468 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter]
>
> 11:47:06.468 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter] FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.
>
> 11:47:06.468 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter]
>
> 11:47:06.469 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter] * What went wrong:
>
> 11:47:06.469 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter] Execution failed for task ':Examples:UIExplorer:android:app:compileDebugJavaWithJavac'.
>
> 11:47:06.469 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter] > Compilation failed; see the compiler error output for details.
>
> 11:47:06.469 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter]
>
> 11:47:06.469 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter] * Try:
>
> 11:47:06.470 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter] Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace.
>
> 11:47:06.471 [LIFECYCLE] [org.gradle.BuildResultLogger]
>
> 11:47:06.471 [LIFECYCLE] [org.gradle.BuildResultLogger] BUILD FAILED
>
> 11:47:06.471 [LIFECYCLE] [org.gradle.BuildResultLogger]
>
> 11:47:06.471 [LIFECYCLE] [org.gradle.BuildResultLogger] Total time: 14.184 secs
>
> 11:47:07.413 [INFO] [org.gradle.launcher.daemon.client.DaemonClient] Received result Failure[value=org.gradle.initialization.ReportedException: org.gradle.internal.exceptions.LocationAwareException: Execution failed for task
>
> ':Examples:UIExplorer:android:app:compileDebugJavaWithJavac'.] from daemon DaemonInfo{pid=23827, address=[0c64a320-a8e2-43e3-ad0a-0b3dfff7feca port:65276, addresses:[/0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1, /127.0.0.1]], idle=true,
>
> context=DefaultDaemonContext[uid=dba435c0-a637-4e5b-8486-166f81a1489c,javaHome=/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_66.jdk/Contents/Home,daemonRegistryDir=/Users/xxx/.gradle/daemon,pid=23827,idleTimeout=10800000,daemonOpts=-XX> :MaxPermSize=256m,-XX:+HeapDumpOnOutOfMemoryError,-Xmx1024m,-Dfile.encoding=UTF-8,-Duser.country=US,-Duser.language=en,-Duser.variant]} (build should be done).

and using the -info parameter also returns the same information

> Executing task ':Examples:UIExplorer:android:app:compileDebugJavaWithJavac' (up-to-date check took 0.004 secs) due to:
>     No history is available.
>   All input files are considered out-of-date for incremental task ':Examples:UIExplorer:android:app:compileDebugJavaWithJavac'.
>   Compiling with JDK Java compiler API.
>   /Users/xxx/gitRepo/react-native/Examples/UIExplorer/android/app/src/main/java/UIExplorerActivity.java:63: error: cannot find symbol
>         mReactInstanceManager.onPause();
>                              ^
>     symbol:   method onPause()
>     location: variable mReactInstanceManager of type ReactInstanceManager
>   /Users/xxx/gitRepo/react-native/Examples/UIExplorer/android/app/src/main/java/UIExplorerActivity.java:72: error: cannot find symbol
>         mReactInstanceManager.onResume(this, this);
>                              ^
>     symbol:   method onResume(UIExplorerActivity,UIExplorerActivity)
>     location: variable mReactInstanceManager of type ReactInstanceManager
>   2 errors
>   :Examples:UIExplorer:android:app:compileDebugJavaWithJavac FAILED
>   :Examples:UIExplorer:android:app:compileDebugJavaWithJavac (Thread[Daemon worker Thread 5,5,main]) completed. Took 0.418 secs.
>
> FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.
>
> - What went wrong:
>     Execution failed for task ':Examples:UIExplorer:android:app:compileDebugJavaWithJavac'.
>     Compilation failed; see the compiler error output for details.
> - Try:
>     Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --debug option to get more log output.
>
> BUILD FAILED
>
> Total time: 7.151 secs
>   Stopped 0 compiler daemon(s).
>   Received result Failure[value=org.gradle.initialization.ReportedException: org.gradle.internal.exceptions.LocationAwareException: Execution failed for task ':Examples:UIExplorer:android:app:compileDebugJavaWithJavac'.] from daemon DaemonInfo{pid=23827, address=[0c64a320-a8e2-43e3-ad0a-0b3dfff7feca port:65276, addresses:[/0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1, /127.0.0.1]], idle=true, context=DefaultDaemonContext[uid=dba435c0-a637-4e5b-8486-166f81a1489c,javaHome=/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_66.jdk/Contents/Home,daemonRegistryDir=/Users/xxx/.gradle/daemon,pid=23827,idleTimeout=10800000,daemonOpts=-XX:MaxPermSize=256m,-XX:+HeapDumpOnOutOfMemoryError,-Xmx1024m,-Dfile.encoding=UTF-8,-Duser.country=US,-Duser.language=en,-Duser.variant]} (build should be done).

using --stacktrace returns

> org.gradle.api.tasks.TaskExecutionException: Execution failed for task ':Examples:UIExplorer:android:app:compileDebugJavaWithJavac'.
>       at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.executeActions(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:69)
>       at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.execute(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:46)

... (did not want to put the whole stacktrace unless you want it)

All the types of errors indicate that UIExplorerActivity.java has an error onPause() and onResume() while compiling.

I have already looked at similar issues on this list, including 
- https://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues/5790
- https://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues/4858

as well as issues on stackoverflow, including

[React native Android Example does not work](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32643775/react-native-android-example-does-not-work)

[React Native make android app load in genymotion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34744145/react-native-make-android-app-load-in-genymotion)

and a few others but they do not appear to be related to this issue (as it is either a different class that is failing or a different issue that causes the same result.

**Notes: building the iOS version works fine (with xCode etc.).**

How to fix this?  Any insight appreciated. thanks..

Edward

Answer (score 0):

In conjunction with the #react-native devs on github, an answer was reached:

https://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues/6107

to summarize:

- The repo was updated two days ago (Feb 22nd, 2016) to correct the issue described above - https://github.com/facebook/react-native/commit/ad17a2f2908f430b05fd2836d3f08873988bce10 . so **git pull** the latest repo
- update **node-haste** to 2.3.0
- update npm-shrinkwrap.json ... code is below

  "node-haste": {

  "version": "2.3.0",
  "from": "node-haste@>=2.2.0 <3.0.0",
  "dependencies": {

  and at a terminal prompt...

> npm install node-haste

then follow the instructions to run react-native examples on mac simulating android with android simulator

> ./gradlew :Examples:Movies:android:app:installDebug
>
> ./packager/packager.sh

then all should work. (at the time of this writing. react-native updates frequently)